# How to create an object without calling constructor function and new keyword

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function Person (I use ES5 for this example)

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name
}

Person.prototype.printName = function() {
  console.log(this.name)
}
```

As I understand, my newly created object ".**proto**" reference should be equal to Person.prototype (like new operator does). I use Object.create to set appropriate **proto**. How should I pass additional arguments to my newly created instance so that my 'TestName' argument should be equal to this.name

Create instance function itself:

```
function createInstance(constructor, ...args) {
  let instance = Object.create(constructor.prototype)
  instance.call(constructor, args)
  return instance
}
```

```
let instance = createInstance(Person, 'TestName')
console.log(instance)
```

Comment: Use `apply` instead of `call`, or just go for the spread operator. Or even better just use `Reflect.construct` :-)

Comment: I i am not mistaken shouldn't it be ```constructor.apply(instance, ...args)``` ? (notice constructor and instance switched)

Comment: I guess you're right. That makes sense and works :)

Comment: This is an often question from interviews (create an instance without a new operator) also after creating a new instance. instance.__proto__ should be equal to Person.prototype